# Can I declare a very large array in a class, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, bigdata

I am trying to write a class to store millions 3D coordinates data. At the first, I tried to use a 3D array to store those coordinates data.

```
#ifndef DUMPDATA_H
#define DUMPDATA_H
#define ATOMNUMBER 2121160
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class DumpData
{
public:
    DumpData(string filename);
    double m_atomCoords[ATOMNUMBER][3];
};
#endif // DUMPDATA_H
```

Then I compiled the program, but I got segfaults when I run the program in ubuntu 14.04 system (64 bit). So I changed the 3D array to vector by declaring:

```
vector < vector <double> > m_atomCoords;
```

Then the program worked. 
I am just wondering are there limitations of declaring very large arrays in a class?

Comment: 48mb isn't that much unless you're declaring a non-static local variable, then you'll likely run out of stack space.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious 8mb? `2121160*8*3/1024/1024` give me 48

Comment: @BryanChen Just missed the 4 while typing. Oops.

Comment: For this question mentioning your operation system would be fine since Windows and Linux use stack differently

Comment: @frans It's Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the stack has a limited size.

This will likely cause a stack overflow:

```
int main() {
    DumpData x;
}
```

While these won't:

```
int main() {
    static DumpData x;
    std::unique_ptr<DumpData> y = std::make_unique<DumpData>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack is a very precious and scarce resource, so I'd just use the **heap** to allocate big data.

If you have an array of 3D coordinates, instead of using a `vector<vector<double>>`, I'd just define a class to represent a 3D point, using just three separate `double` data members, or a *raw* array of three `double`s, e.g.:

```
class Point3D {
 private:
  double m_vec[3]; // X, Y and Z

  // or:
  // double x;
  // double y;
  // double z; 

 public:
  double X() const {
    return m_vec[0];
    // or:
    // return x;
  }   
  ... other setters/getters, etc.
};
```

and then I'd just use a **`std::vector<Point3D>`** as a data member inside your `DumpData` class.

(A `Point3D` class defined as above has less overhead than a `std::vector<double>`, and also offers an higher level of semantics, so it's a better choice.)

With the default allocator, `std::vector` will allocate the memory for the huge number of `Point3D`s from the *heap* (not from the stack), which works well, and it is also hidden from the client of `DumpData`, making a nice simple public interface for the `DumpData` class.